# Different types of patent in Pharma

Tags: patent-infringement

1. What are the differnet types of patent one can have on a molecule?
2. What is the difference between composition patent and polymorphic patent?
3. How to know if a particular patent is Method of Use or Polymorphic patent?
4. Is there a way to know if there is a Para-IV/ FTF filing on a patented molecule?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the differnet types of patent one can have on a molecule?

1. Product Claims
2. Isomer
3. Synthetic Derivatives
4. Proportion of Different Products
5. Impurity profile
6. Structure
7. Physical form of molecule
8. Size of crystal
9. Use of molecule
10. Dosage forms
11. Treatment methods using molecules
12. Delivery methods (doubtful)

> What is the difference between composition patent and polymorphic
>   patent?

Composition patent involves two or more chemically distinct products and there physical mixture; wherein Polymorphic patents crystallization structure of product is changed by way of process modification it has different crystallization profile.

> How to know if a particular patent is Method of Use or Polymorphic
>   patent?

mostly by reading claim preamble it is evident if it is of use or structure.

> Is there a way to know if there is a Para-IV/ FTF filing on a patented
>   molecule?

You need to crosscheck the FDA website [ORANGE BOOK](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ob/) for patent listings. And [ANDA  lists published on FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/HowDrugsareDevelopedandApproved/ApprovalApplications/AbbreviatedNewDrugApplicationANDAGenerics/ucm147166.htm)